# How to check image extension

Tags: javascript, php, file

```
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents(basename($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])));
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) && file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) //image is selected
{
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($ext == 'png' ||$ext == 'jpeg'||$ext == 'jpg')
    {
        //$insertQuery 
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Please select correct picture format")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
```

The problem is that I can't get/validate the file extension. Every time I upload a photo that matches the condition, it will only show me the "select correct picture" message.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: debug: `echo $ext`

Comment: Also consider case sensitivity

Comment: @ngod what mean?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i tried all the alphabet already

Comment: add an `echo $ext;` so you can see exactly what the `pathinfo()` as found

Comment: where from `$filename` come

Comment: You need to actually _save_ your image somewhere before you can try to check its extension. consider using `move_uploaded_file` to a temporary storage location unaccessible from the web

Answer (score 0):

you can use php built-in **pathinfo** function.

```
<?php
$supported_image = array(
    'gif',
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png'
);

$src_file_name = 'abskwlfd.PNG';
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($src_file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Using strtolower to overcome case sensitive
if (in_array($ext, $supported_image)) {
    echo "it's image";
} else {
    echo 'not image';
}
?>
```